# Upper and lower limits of 'alternating' sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limsup-and-liminf

> Suppose $(a_n)$ is a real sequence and $a_1,a_3,a_5,\ldots$ converges to $s$, and $a_2,a_4,a_6,\ldots$ converges to $i$ where $s\ge i$, where $s=+\infty$ and $i=-\infty$ is a possibility, then is it always true that $\limsup_\limits{n\to \infty} a_n=s$ and $\liminf_\limits{n\to \infty} a_n=i$ ? If yes, then why?

Comment: Yes. Cause, you can stick a real number between two non-equal real numbers

Comment: Any converging (or tending to $+\infty$, or tending to $-\infty$) subsequence has infinitely many terms in either $a_{2n}$ or in $a_{2n+1}$, therefore it must converge to $s$ or to $i$. Since $\liminf$ is the infimum of the limits of all converging subsequences, that must be $i$. Similarly for $\limsup$.

Comment: Indeed, you can show by contradiction that if there is a third cluster point then it must be equal to either $s$ or $i$ (or both if $s=i$) for the reason given by @treeleaf